# I am trying to compare 2 sets of integer values to check for a match in a lottery ticket scenario

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am fairly new to Java and am struggling with this concept. As I have said I am trying to make a comparison between 2 sets of integer values, one set I have retrieved from the website using HTML parsing and stored in an array (`Integer [] numbers = new Integer[split.length]`).
The other set of values I have retrieved from user input and have stored in the array `userNumbers` (`int userNumbers = new int [SIZE]`). I attempted to use the if condition to make the comparison i.e. `if (userNumber[count] == number [0])`.

However I am getting errors and the IDE is not allowing me to enter the number array part of the comparison. Can anyone help me to understand why this is or instruct me as to what I may be doing wrong? Here is the code in full.
Help is very much appreciated in advance.

```
public class lotteryNumbers
{
   static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      //link to the intended web site
      try {
         Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.national-lottery.co.uk/player/p/drawHistory.do").get();

         Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("drawhistory");
         Element table = elements.first();
         Element tbody = table.getElementsByTag("tbody").first();

         Element firstLottoRow = tbody.getElementsByClass("lottorow").first();

         Element dateElement = firstLottoRow.child(0);
         System.out.println(dateElement.text());

         Element gameElement = firstLottoRow.child(1);
         System.out.println(gameElement.text());

         Element noElement = firstLottoRow.child(2);
         System.out.println(noElement.text());

         String [] split = noElement.text().split(" - ");
         // set up an array to store numbers from the latest draw on the lottery web page
         Integer [] numbers = new Integer [split.length];

         int i = 0;
         for (String strNo : split) {
            numbers [i] = Integer.valueOf(strNo);
            i++;
         }

         for (Integer no : numbers) {
            System.out.println(no);
         }

         Element bonusElement = firstLottoRow.child(3);
         Integer bonusBall = Integer.valueOf(bonusElement.text());
         System.out.println("Bonus ball: " + bonusBall);
         //Elements elementsHtml = doc.getElementsByTag("main-article-content");

      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();

      }
      final int SIZE = 7;
      //array to store user numbers
      int [] userNumbers = new int[SIZE];
      //array to check if user number is present with web numbers
      boolean [] present = new boolean[7];
      int counter = 0;
      while (counter<SIZE)
      {
         System.out.println("enter your numbers");
         userNumbers[counter]=keyboard.nextInt();
         counter++;
      }
      for (int count: userNumbers)
              System.out.println(count);

      if (userNumbers[0] ==      )
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What do you mean by not allowing you to type? What error is it showing?

Comment: In the if statement after ive typed (userNumbers[0] == ) and I try and type number [0] as I am trying to make a comparison between the position[0] of the userNumbers array with position [0] of numbers array but the Intellij IDE automatically corrects this to "userNumbers" so it doesnt recognise "numbers" at this point. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numbers` local variable is declared in the `try{...}` block. Thus it is not accessible outside it.

If you declare it before the `try{` line it will work:

```
Integer[] numbers;
try {
  ...
  // set numbers here
  ...
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
// can use numbers here
```

If it is the only value you need from the HTML-parsing code you may even refactor the `try/catch` structure to a method returning the data for `numbers`.

And by the way, I advise you not to try `int == Integer`, prefer `int == int`. It is usually clearer and you won't have to guess if the `int` will be boxed or the `Integer` unboxed.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume that tip that you suggested about including the numbers array outside the try/catch has solved the problem! and I take your other advice on board. Many thanks I appreciate that!